# Protocol Translation from CAN bus to IP

Tags: raspberry-pi, ip, network-protocols, can-bus, snort

I am trying to detect intrusions on a CAN bus configuration. To do this I want to try protocol conversion from CAN to IP (UDP) in order to use snort. I really don't know where to begin as I have not seen anything on protocol translation for a CAN bus at all. Is it even possible? Has anyone tried it?

I basically used a raspberry pi and several Arduinos to take temperature readings (from thermostats) and control hot/cold fans in order to regulate temperature. I know this is not a lot to go on, but as I said, I am just in the beginning phase of planning this protocol translation.

Comment: Most so-called "CAN bus intrusions" are 1) incompetent designer allows update of critical MCU firmware over Internet 2) hacker completely replaces all firmware with their own program 3) the CAN bus happens to be connected to the MCU. There isn't actually anyone "hacking" the CAN bus itself remotely. Or do you simply wish to detect unknown CAN frames on the bus?

Comment: @Lundin Thanks for the input...I thought I read that a vehicle CAN bus can be hacked remotely?  Anyway basically I would like to monitor CAN traffic...I want to know if someone is trying to intrude.  So for instance, let's say I have a self driving car (for argument sake, ignore any technologies of a self driving car that don't align with current CAN operations in a normal vehicle)... lets say I want to monitor this vehicle, make sure all operations are going as planned.  Someone hops in the car and plugs in.  Is there a way I could monitor the CAN with SNORT, so I could halt operations.

Comment: Still much too broad. If someone would plug in physically to the CAN bus, they would send frames already present on the bus, but with different data. The only way you can detect that is if you have hard real-time requirements of the frames. A "physical hacker" would then also have to match the frame timing, which is difficult to do from a PC laptop - basically it would depend on the quality of their CAN-to-USB gateway. Other than that, there's no way to do it, save for encryption or time stamps in the application layer protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cannelloni](https://github.com/mguentner/cannelloni) on your RPi. There are also stand-alone CAN-to-TCP/UDP converters like for example this [one](https://shop-visionsystems.de/en/ethernet-to-can-bus/424-netcan-plus-110.html).

Comment: Any more info as far as moving forward and how to go about the cannelloni process would be great if you had time...

Comment: For cannelloni you'll need a Linux host with a virtual CAN interface (vcan0) connected to the real CAN interface on your RPi. Then you'll need to understand cannelloni protocol in order to configure/extend snort. Though I think it would be much simpler to detect wrong CAN messages on your RPi and then inform your main infrastructure about the intrusion.